# Is header() in PHP a Asynchronous function?

Tags: php, asynchronous, header

Here is a piece of code in process.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['skip'])) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: main.php'); 
    } else {
        if(!empty($_SESSION['nameErr']) || !empty($_SESSION['quoteErr'])) {
            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
                // echo 'new record';
                session_destroy();
                header('Location: main.php');
            } else{
                // echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a form with two 'submit' buttons in index.php file:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
                <span class="error"> <?php if (isset($_SESSION['nameErr']))
                 {echo $_SESSION['nameErr'];}?> </span> <br>
                <label> Your name: <span>*</span>
                <input type="text" name="name"> </label><br/>
                <span class="error"> <?php if (isset($_SESSION['quoteErr'])) 
                {echo $_SESSION['quoteErr'];}?> </span> <br>
                <label> Your quote: <span>*</span>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="quote"></textarea></label><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Add my quote!"name="add"> 
                <input type="submit" value="Skip to quotes!" name="skip">
            </form>
```

If the 'skip' button is clicked, then redirect to 'main.php' page. The above code in process.php works, but if I changed a little bit:

```
if(isset($_POST['skip'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: main.php'); 
} 
    if(!empty($_SESSION['nameErr']) || !empty($_SESSION['quoteErr'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
            // echo 'new record';
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: main.php');
        } else{
            // echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }
```

When click the 'skip' button, it still stays in the index page. I'm wonder if that because header() is an asynchronous function in PHP? I couldn't find any official reference to it. Please provide some tips. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll want to `exit` or `die` after the Location header call.

Comment: To expand on the previous comment- `header('location: blah');` doesn't stop subsequent code execution. Browsers can also choose to ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `$_POST['skip']` set, you execute `session_destroy();`.

Then your sessions will be **destroyed**, therefore:

`!empty($_SESSION['nameErr']) || !empty($_SESSION['quoteErr'])` will always be **false**.

And then it comes to this condition:

```
if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
    // echo 'new record';
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: main.php');
} else{
    // echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Check if that mysqli_query actually returns **true** otherwise it will always end up on **index.php**

Answer (score 1):

The header function sends a raw http header to the browser. In case of the location tag, it sends a redirect header to the browser which in turn opens the new location, after the script execution finished.

To prevent execution of code after sending the redirection header, you should exit the script.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, **header()** is not asynchronous function in PHP. Whats happening above is since you have removed **else** block, that code is executed anyway. This line `if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {` is returning **false** and your code is ultimately reaching line `header('Location: index.php');` which is overriding the location header and resetting it the same index.php page.

There could be multiple solutions for this problem, one could be as *dn Fer* mentioned, use **exit()** function after setting location header if you want that to be the final redirection.